# using over sampling in imbalanced-learn in python

Tags: python, pip, imblearn

I installed `imblearn` and confirmed the package exists in:

```
C:\Users\ddd\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages
```

i.e., there is a folder with this name which implies that it was installed.

But whenever I used the following command:

```py
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
```

I encounter this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imblearn'
```

Is there a fix?

Comment: Install imblearn `pip install imblearn` or  `pip3 install imblearn` for python-3.x. Project is upgraded to `pip install imbalanced-learn`. Have a look at https://pypi.org/project/imbalanced-learn/

Comment: @ismaildurmaz I think I installed it correctly with pip install imblearn. Still, I receive the same error.

Comment: Have you ever checked the package is listed with `pip list`? Maybe you don't use that environment. Be sure that you use it.

Comment: @ismaildurmaz Yes it is installed and in pip list.